# Can i point multiple location to same hive external table?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I need to process the multiple months data simultaneously. So, is there an option to point multiple folders to external table? 
e.g.
`Create external table logdata(col1 string, col2 string........) location s3://logdata/april, s3://logdata/march`

Comment: I haven't done that before but I guess you can use join operation to accomplish that. One more option can be of using concept of view it will enable reporting stuff also easy as you just need to expose view not your original tables. Let me know if this helps or any questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple answer: no, the `location` of a Hive `external` table during creation has to be unique, this is needed by the metastore to understand where your table lives.

That being said, you can probably get away with using partitions: you can specify a `location` for each of your partitions which seems to be what you want ultimately since you are splitting by month.

So create your table like this:

```
create external table logdata(col1 string, col2 string) partitioned by (month string) location 's3://logdata'
```

Then you can add partitions like this:

```
alter table logdata add partition(month='april') location 's3://logdata/april'
```

You do this for every month, and now you can query your table specifying whichever partition you want, and Hive will only look at the directories for which you actually want data (for example if you're only processing april and june, Hive will not load may)

Comment: Thanks Charles first of all for the suggestion......just one more little query i don't have any column like 'month' in my raw data. So still can i partition using month, the way you described?

Comment: You don't need to have a column named month, if you create a partition in Hive this will just correspond to the directory, so you should be fine and be able to query your data with `select * from logdata where month='april'`

Comment: That will work for /location/month=april. but what if we don't have month= in our directories. How do we have to partition the hives for a directories that subdirectories are 20160101 and 20160102 ? @CharlesMenguy

Answer (score 2):

I checked out your scenario. I think you can achieve that by using multiple load inpath statements for enabling multiple locations .
Below are the steps I took for the test I ran.

```
hive> create external table xxx (uid int, name string, dept string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;
hive> load data inpath '/input/tmp/user_bckt' into table xxx;
hive> load data inpath '/input/user_bckt' into table xxx;
hive> select count(*) from xxx;
10
hive> select * from xxx;
1   ankur   abinitio
2   lokesh  cloud
3   yadav   network
4   sahu    td
5   ankit   data
1   ankur   abinitio
2   lokesh  cloud
3   yadav   network
4   sahu    td
5   ankit   data
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you

**EDIT:** I just checked the data is getting moved in this case into the hive warehouse opposed to the concept of external table data being left at its original location which is demonstrated below:

```
hduser@hadoopnn:~$ hls /input/tmp
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/10/05 14:47:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser hadoop         93 2014-10-04 18:54 /input/tmp/dept_bckt
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser hadoop         71 2014-10-04 18:54 /input/tmp/user_bckt
hduser@hadoopnn:~$ hcp /input/tmp/user_bckt /input/user_bckt
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/10/05 14:47:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
hduser@hadoopnn:~$ logout
Connection to nn closed.
hduser@hadoopdn2:~$ hls /input/tmp/
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/10/05 15:05:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser hadoop         93 2014-10-04 18:54 /input/tmp/dept_bckt
hduser@hadoopdn2:~$ hls /hive/wh/xxx
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/10/05 15:21:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser hadoop         71 2014-10-04 18:54 /hive/wh/xxx/user_bckt
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser hadoop         71 2014-10-05 14:47 /hive/wh/xxx/user_bckt_copy_1
```

I am currently looking into the issue here and will get back once done.

Answer (score 1):

NO, the location must be single directory.  However, you can alter location to point to multiple directories.  But, when you would query table, it will be an error.

Example:
1.  Alter the location of table as below.  I entered two hdfs directories separated by ‘:’, also tried ‘,’ and ';'.  It was successful.

```
hive> alter table ext set location 'hdfs:///solytr:/ext';
OK
Time taken: 0.086 seconds
```

2. But, when the table was queried, it resulted into failure.

> hive> select * from ext;
>       OK
>       Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /solytr:/ext from hdfs:/solytr:/ext is not a valid DFS filename.
>       
> Time taken: 0.057 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SymlinkTextInputFormat  / https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1272. Think that could solve your problem. Just have to maintain an separate text file with all locations!

Also see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-951 which isn't solved but would be an solution!

Comment: i tried the approach which is given in HIVE-951. But could figured out what sould be the syntax of location. The one given (LOCATION 's3://my.bucket/' 'folder/2009.*\.bz2$') doesn't work. There is an space betwen s3 path and your regedx. Moreover, when i delete the space it load the incorrect data.